# Como reiniciar app no emulador do android studio sem recuperar estado?

Tags: android-studio

Criei uma tela de login e implementei a autenticação. Se há usuário logado, a tela principal é mostrada, se não, a tela de login é mostrada. Depois que loguei para testar o Android Studio salvou o estado no emulador, de modo que não vai mais pra a tela de login. O que fazer para resetar isso? Alguma ideia?

Comment: Já tentei "cold start", mas não resolveu!

Comment: android-studio é um software de desenvolvimento, o emulador é a parte, se esta travado na tela de login é porque fez algo para ficar assim, logo isso parece problema no seu aplicativo e não no android-studio.

Comment: Guilherme, não é problema do aplicativo. Não esta travando na tela de login. O fluxo é o seguinte: ao iniciar o app, é feita a autenticacao (firebase), se não há usuário logado, a tela de login é mostrada. Se há usuário logado, é mostrada não a tela de login, mas sim a tela principal. Quando loguei a primeira vez para testar deu tudo certo, logo em seguida fechei o emulador e vi uma mensagem dizendo o estado seria salvo. Ou seja, como o estado "logado" logado foi salvo, toda vez que compilo, ele vai direto pra main.

Comment: Mas pra mim isso parece sim coisa do app, até aonde entendo a regra de negócio do aplicativo tem que ser definida, sabendo de onde deve começar e checando se esta recuperando ou não, mas sem detalhes fica dificil de saber o que ocorreu.

Comment: Cara, na verdade vc estava certo! É que estou seguindo umas aulas e o professor simplesmente não explicou essa parte. Nos comentários da aula havia vários pessoas com o mesmo problema que eu. Resolvi usando mAuth.signOut() até que chegue a parte de implementar o logout! Obrigado, graças ao seus comentários consegui achar uma solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abra o VMD ( Virtual Device Manager ) e selecione `Cold Boot Now` na coluna de Acções do seu dispositivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No termial pode fazer assim:

```
$ emulator -avd Nome_Do_Dispositivo -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot
```

Remover a pasta `.idea` da pasta do seu aplicativo também deve resolver.

Comment: Com o Cold Boot não resolveu, vou tentar remover as pasta .idea pra ver!

Comment: Tente com os comandos do terminal